# LibGdx `ShapeRenderer` on Android does not honor alpha channel

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx

I have a program where I am drawing some lines on each frame using `ShapeRenderer`. On each frame I want to draw on top the previous, faded by a amount, frame.
So what I am doing is first draw a black rectangle with an alpha less than 1 and then draw the current frame. On desktop it works well and the result is something like this

[image]

But on Android it does not work. It renders like this.

[image]

I tried enabling blending before drawing rectangle

```
Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Also tried seting the alpha channel to 8 bits in `AndroidApplicationConfiguration` (`config.a = 8`)
Nothing of these worked. What else can I try?
Also is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Screen code

```
package com.waterpaw.trochoids.screen;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.ScreenViewport;
import com.waterpaw.trochoids.Trochoid;
import com.waterpaw.trochoids.Trochoids;

public class GameScreen extends BaseScreen {
    private ShapeRenderer sr;

    private ScreenViewport viewport;

    private List<Trochoid> trochoids = new ArrayList<Trochoid>();

    public GameScreen(Trochoids game) {
        super(game);

        viewport = new ScreenViewport();
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
        sr = new ShapeRenderer();
    }

    private int resized;

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        viewport.update(width, height);

        trochoids.clear();
        trochoids.add(new Trochoid(viewport.getWorldWidth(), viewport.getWorldHeight()));
        resized = 2;
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        if(resized-- > 0) {
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        }
        processInput();

        if(!trochoids.get(0).isPaused()) {
            updateTrochoids();
            renderTrochoids();
        }
    }

    private void processInput() {
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Keys.P)) {
            if(trochoids.get(0).isPaused()) {
                trochoids.get(0).unpause();
            } else {
                trochoids.get(0).pause();
            }
        } else if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Keys.SPACE)) {
            touchDown(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        sr.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {
        trochoids.get(0).initialize();
        return true;
    }

    public void renderTrochoids() {
        sr.setProjectionMatrix(viewport.getCamera().combined);

        float w = viewport.getWorldWidth();
        float h = viewport.getWorldHeight();
        sr.setColor(0, 0, 0, 0.1f);
        sr.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
        sr.rect(-w / 2, -h / 2, w, h);
        sr.end();

        sr.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
        for(int i = 0; i < trochoids.size(); i++) {
            trochoids.get(i).render(sr);
        }
        sr.end();
    }

    private void updateTrochoids() {
        for(int i = 0; i < trochoids.size(); i++) {
            trochoids.get(i).update();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 How can I see that? Shouldn't setting config.a = 8 solve this problem?

Comment: Set all four colors of the config to 8. A phone only supports a certain set of combinations. 5658 is almost certainly not one of them, so then LibGDX has to pick for you and that could be unpredictable. That's not your problem, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LibGDX uses double buffering on Android, so your technique won't work. Draw to a FrameBuffer so you can ensure your previous drawing is not cleared every other frame.  Then draw the FrameBuffer's color texture to the screen on every frame.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to avoid this, because I read somewhere that it is expensive, but I'll give it a try.

Comment: When you draw the FrameBuffer to screen, make sure blending is off. Shouldn't be a problem for what you're doing.